# fopen C, statement with no effect?

Tags: c, fopen

I have one error that I have no idea about... I tried to open file either to write or read and check whether opening was successful. but I get this compilation error... I don't know why;;;

```
FILE * infile;
....
infile = fopen(filename, "w");
if(!infile)
   return NULL;
```

and it gives me this error

```
warning: statement with no effect 
error: expected ';' before 'return'
```

It is not definately previous messed up semicolons because if I erase that part of code everything works fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the call to `foepn()` a typo here or in the code?

Comment: As implied by the previous comment by Dan Fego, make sure that you're calling the function `fopen` not `foepn` in your actual code.

Comment: The problem lies in the code that you haven't shown us. Please provide more context. Distill your program to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates your problem, and then post the result in its entirety here. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Have you tried `if (infile == NULL) return NULL;` instead?

Comment: @aardvarkk I just tried and it is same

Comment: @Rob   that is the line causes problem. If I comment that error checking line, everything works fine

Comment: @in Whatever Steps: Copy and paste your actual program here instead of typing something in. It's ok to delete lines, but don't edit stuff, because this sounds like something that's going to boil down into a simple typo.

Comment: @inHisSteps - that warning relies upon the surrounding context. We can only know why this lines has no effect by examining the subsequent lines. For example, is the next (not shown) line `return 0;` If so, the `if` is redundant. Please provide complete context so that we can help you find the error.

Comment: The problem lies in the code that you are not showing us.

Comment: Show more code!!! Otherwise its not possible

Comment: Run your code with `gcc -E` to expand the preprocessors. Then  check the line with `return`. You might get a clue.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly the problem is one that you're subconsciously not seeing, so much so that you automatically corrected it when you copied the code to your message above.  The error message says that you have a `;` immediately before a `return`, meaning your actual code is almost certainly

```
if(!infile);
   return NULL;
```

and the warning is telling you that the `if` is meaningless, due to the fact that the statement it is guarding is empty (the `;` at the end of the `if` line), and the return will be executed unconditionally.

Comment: The error message says **expected** `';'` before `return`. That doesn't match `if (!infile);`.

Comment: @Daniel -- its equally likely the error message was miscopied.  Without the actual code that the OP is using, all we can do is guess what is going wrong.

Comment: My gcc warns "suggest braces around empty body in an »if« statement" if I have `if (condition);`, so I would consider that less likely. Definitely a possibility, however. Cooperation from OP would help indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Have you included stdio.h?
- Is this function supposed to return a value?
- Is NULL actually defined? (Try returning just 0)

Which line is reporting that warning? Is it really one of the lines you posted?

Comment: if(!infile) return NULL; line is reporting the warning and error NULL is defined and if I comment that line everything works out fine and the function only consists of those lines

Comment: The function only consists of those lines? Surely there's some code following that uses 'infile'? More context is needed here.